# Proof of Accommodation: One day trip in France

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, france, proof-of-accommodation

I am an Indian citizen planning to travel from London to Paris for a day and then return back to London on the same day itself. 
In this case what do I do to show proof of accomodation for my Schengen visa application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof of accommodation is where you will be staying/sleeping for the duration of your trip. I recommend not providing any accommodation and adding a note saying you will only go for 1 day or just put the address of your house as that is where you will be sleeping (if you have to provide something).